# making perl executables on windows

Tags: perl, windows-7, executable

1. hi experts,
2. I want to make a executable from simple perl script in dir **D:\script.pl** (just prints hello world)
3. I want to do this using **PAR::pp**. I have installed it using cpanm PAR.
4. Could someone **show actual steps**. As i tried pp -o name.exe D:\script.pl both in cmd prompt and padre, but no success. Error : **pp is not recognized as internal or external command** . . .
5. Also there are some more questions, which I want to discuss, but want to clear above one first.
6. System info : Windows 7, 32 bit, PAR 1.007 , Strawberry perl 5 v14 sub ver2 v5.14.2. Padre IDE.
7. **Does PAR archive mean a set up file?**

Comment: Why numbering in question?

Comment: Don't know when but got habit of writing everything point wise. Is it annoying or good habit?

Comment: I will recommend to use numbering only if needed. Numbering every line will actually make others miss on highlights of your question. Use only for particular or specific points in your question. It is a good habit if used properly and will give you upvotes just for numbering or formatting properly, because then the question becomes much more readable for others and they feel interested in it.:)

Answer (score 3):

[`pp`](https://metacpan.org/module/pp) doesn't actually come with `PAR` anymore, you must install the [`PAR::Packer`](https://metacpan.org/module/PAR%3a%3aPacker) distribution to get that.

Comment: Results of cpanm PAR::packer / cpanm App::Packer. Configuring OK. .Building and testing failed.Installing PAR packer failed.

Comment: It seems that pp has many filed bugs: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=PAR-Packer

Comment: see activestate's availability matrix, this at least gives an idea of where you might find success: http://code.activestate.com/ppm/PAR-Packer/

Comment: I have to agree.  My success with PAR::pp has been spotty at best. Any script that is even a little bit complex has issues with packing.  Sometimes it packs and then doesn't run right.  Really odd.  Does anyone have better ways of making executables from perl scripts in Windows?

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is pack (pure-Perl) dependencies using [App::FatPacker](https://metacpan.org/module/App::FatPacker) then distributing Strawberry Perl and the fat-packed script.